# Upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 2 - formCollection.ToValueProvider()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type IValueProvider to IDictionary

When I try to run the code below:

```
IDictionary<string, ValueProviderResult> valueProvider = formValues.ToValueProvider();
foreach (string k in formValues.Keys)
{
    ModelState.SetModelValue(k, valueProvider[k]);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am using .NET 4.0 I had to do this:

```
IValueProvider valueProvider = formValues.ToValueProvider();
foreach (string k in formValues.Keys)
{
    ModelState.SetModelValue(k, valueProvider.GetValue(k));
}
```

I want to say thanks to @abatishchev for pointing out the differences.

Comment: It's rather better to delete this your answer and edit your original question

Comment: really? I thought it was best to have an answer for the question?

Comment: Sorry I just didn't understand that's your own answer to your question! Glad to hear you found the solution. Approve it now

Answer (score 0):

You do second, superfluous dictionary lookup:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ValueProviderResult> pair in formValues)
{
    ModelState.SetModelValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Very strange!

in [3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.tovalueprovider%28VS.90%29.aspx) `ToValueProvider()` returns `IDictionary<string, ValueProviderResult>`

and

but in [4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.tovalueprovider.aspx) - it returns `IValueProvider`

Comment: @dean: have you any results with cast?